# I think there is a type mismatch in default definition in instance Applicative Maybe in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, applicative

I am currently studying Haskell with Prof. Hutton's "Programming in Haskell", and I found something strange regarding the definition of Maybe as an instance of the class Applicative.

In `GHC.Base`, the instance `Applicative Maybe` is defined as follows:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
  pure = Just

  Just f  <*> m       = fmap f m
  Nothing <*> _m      = Nothing
```

It is the line which defines the value of `Nothing <\*> _` as `Nothing` that bothers me. `Nothing` is of type `Maybe a`, where the operator `<*>` actually requires `f (a -> b)` (in this case, `Maybe (a -> b)`) as its first argument's type. Therefore, this is a type mismatch, which Haskell should complain about. However, this is accepted as a default definition, and therefore Haskell does not complain about it where I think it should.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `a` in `Maybe a` is a type variable, and can be any type at all!  So `Nothing` can have the type `Maybe Int`, or `Maybe [x]`, or `Maybe (p -> q)`, for example. 
 Don't get confused by the fact that the variable name `a` is used in two places.  The `a` in the type of `Nothing` is a completely different variable from the `a` in the type of `<*>`, and just happens to have the same name!

(That's exactly the same as if you wrote `f x = x + 5` and then elsewhere, `g x = "Hello, " ++ x`.  The use of `x` in both places doesn't matter, because they are in different scopes.  Same with the `a` in this types.  Different scopes, so they are different variables.)

Comment: Oh, I get it! So, 'a' in "Maybe a" is a very broad generalization of any type that can be given to the constructor function "Maybe". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let's make things clearer by relabeling a type variable:

```
Nothing :: Maybe x
```

The type `Maybe x` unifies with `Maybe (a -> b)`, with `x ~ (a -> b)`. That is, `Nothing` is a value that can used as `Maybe a` for *any* `a`, including a function type. Thus it is a legal left-hand argument for `<*>` here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Small follow-up question here: should I read x ~ (a -> b) as "the variable x is associated with type (a -> b)"?

Comment: @Namudon'tdie: `x ~ y` is a [type equality constraint](https://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2017/1/haskell-type-equality-constraints). Informally, people use it to mean “the type `x` is equal to the type `y`”; in Haskell, you can use this syntax as a typeclass constraint when certain extensions are enabled (e.g. `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies`). It’s mainly useful for controlling typeclass instance resolution and aiding type-level programming.